# How to apply a single conditional formatting rule to multiple non-contiguous columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to collect separated group of columns in one formula, like here?

I want to skip the E column, and then apply the same format:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 5):

You can define several ranges and append them with commas in the "Applies to" box of the dialog.

[image]

If you use semicolons in formulas, then use a semicolon here, too.

Also, it is not advisable to set conditional formats for whole columns, like in your screenshot. It can make your spreadsheet very slow, because for each column Excel needs to evaluate over a million cells and determine if the format should be applied. That can waste a lot of resources. It's better to include the rows in the ranges used in the Applies to box.

Comment: @J.DOe if this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That's helpful to other users by identifying proven solutions.  It also awards a little rep to both of you for the effort.